# Is there a way to perform Zero Noise Extrapolation with qiskit without using the runtime service?

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

[Qiskit Runtime](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/run/configure-error-mitigation) is capable of performing Zero Noise Extrapolation (ZNE) using the `Estimator` primitive. However, due to memory restrictions on IBM cloud, I would like to perform ZNE using a simulator locally. I would like to use `qiskit.primitives.Estimator` instead of `qiskit_ibm_runtime.Estimator`. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just set ‘backend = service.backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")‘ ?

Comment: I'm struggling to pass the resilience_level to the Estimator. qiskit_ibm_runtime.Estimator accepts qiskit_ibm_runtime.Options object as an argument, but I cannot find an equivalent object for qiskit.primitives.Estimator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qiskit.primitives Estimator is a reference statevector based implementation. It has no noise (other than it can simulate variance for shot/sampling noise) so it has no such capability.

There is an issue against Aer simulator to support noise mitigation, since Aer can support a noise model when doing simulations, but this is still open https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/issues/1658

So at present the Runtime Estimator is the only one supporting that and then only for real devices.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Is it possible to use qiskit.primitives.BackendEstimator instead?

Comment: That does not support it either. That was done more for compatibility with providers that did not natively support primitives and its support is limited.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other ways to implement ZNE besides directly using Qiskit Runtime - there are various libraries and functions that allow you to program ZNE more directly. I recommend [Mitiq](https://github.com/unitaryfund/mitiq) - this allows you to build the circuit folding locally, run the circuits, and then to post-process the results using a variety of extrapolation methods. This also allows you to save the results and post-process them in different ways, if that is of interest to you. If you want to run the circuits on a quantum computer, for example on an IBM Quantum computer, then keep in mind that by default the server-side compilation can sometimes optimize away the circuit folding, so make sure to turn off server side optimization. Using a local simulator can also optimize away the circuit folding, so make sure the optimization level is set to 0.

In summary, for local simulation using a noise model, you could build your folded circuits locally, then just run them using the local Qiskit circuit simulator (Mitiq is Qiskit compatible), and then also post-process your results locally to compute the observables you are interested in.